# Dropbox website does not open and gives SSL related error

Tags: windows, dropbox, website, ssl

When I open the website [www.dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/) in my Windows server 2003 R2 service pack 2 PC, I get error as shown below:
[image]

I checked settings of Internet explorer and everything seems to be ok. Also, date and time of system are proper. I have added the certificate, website to trusted website too. But the website opens properly in all other PC. So what may be the error? How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is the date and time correct on your PC? make sure it's correct to the minute - use an online clock for your city/country

Comment: @BigChris forget to mention that in my question. Time and date are proper

Comment: I have also noticed you have two active network adapters (bottom right of picture)... can you confirm this, and try turning one off and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: Also, have a read of the Dropbox help on this topic: https://www.dropbox.com/help/159/en

Comment: Try also resetting IE's proxy settings so that only "automatically detect settings" is only ticked (or even untick them all if you're not behind a proxy server)